# Openlayers custom control event listener get map

Tags: javascript, custom-controls, openlayers, openlayers-6

I am using `osm` and `openlayers` to display two maps.

I created a custom control:

```
function getDrawPolygonControl() {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-pen"></i>';

  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // how to get the correct map instance here????
    console.log(e);
  });

  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'ol-draw ol-control';
  element.appendChild(button);

  return new ol.control.Control({element: element});
}
```

In my initMap() function i add it to the respective map using:

```
const controls = [new ol.control.FullScreen(), new ol.control.Attribution(), getDrawPolygonControl()];

  const map = new ol.Map({
    view: view,
    target: target,
    controls: controls,
  });
```

The question now is how to i get the correct map instance in my onClick listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the control constructor earlier so you can reference it:

```
function getDrawPolygonControl() {
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-pen"></i>';

  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'ol-draw ol-control';
  element.appendChild(button);

  const control = new ol.control.Control({element: element});

  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(control.getMap());
  });

  return control;
}
```